# path issue of package.json during build

Tags: angular, highcharts, ionic3

i am trying to read package jSon variables in to my components. i have imported package into my components by giving relative path. which is working fine now but at the build time relative path not working. how can i import package into my components which also works fine during build. this is my code `import theme from "../../../../package"`

Comment: i mean package.json

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you were trying to import package.json into your page component?
Usually we are install thrid party modules via npm and its listed in package.json.
We can use module by importing in component like this,

import { myFunction } from 'theLibraryName';

Comment: Thanks for your replay prachi. actually i have two builds for my application(dark theme build and light theme build). so what theme build i'm going to build i will specify in package.json only. that theme build i need to know in component to give theme specific colors to my highcharts.